# Python App engine blobstore unable to get uploaded resources

Tags: python, google-app-engine, blobstore

I am trying to create a simple web application to upload multiple images using Blobstore. I have managed to upload the images successfully to the Blobstore. But when the images get uploaded, it simply shows a blank page with the URL like: myapplicationId.appstore.com/_ah/upload/.…(keyvalue). When I try to get image from key it shows me blank page. I am stuck.
In logs it shows 200 with no size of file.

Following is code snippet.

```
class ServeHandler(blobstore_handlers.BlobstoreDownloadHandler):
  def get(self, resource):
    print "get img"
    resource = str(urllib.unquote(resource))
    blob_info = blobstore.BlobInfo.get(resource)
    self.response.out.write(blob_info)
```

or
        self.send_blob(blob_info)

I have checked the db images are there. this handler is called and I also got print statement working.

I have also deployed the code to GAE same issue on local and GAE as well.

Following is the url I am making.
http://127.0.0.1:8585/serve/9lYtH7BmLoI7qOTaYlG8UA==

Comment: I believe your problem might be that you're **both** writing to `self.response` **and** using `send_blob` -- the former interfering with working of the latter (I don't personally know if it would, as I never tried doing both things in a single response).  What happens if you comment out the `self.response.out.write` call (and the `print` too to make doubly sure -- you can rather do a `logging.info` that's guaranteed not to interfere with the response!-).

Comment: I have tried both one by one but got nothing in response.

Comment: Hmmm, so the URL you say you're making is on your localhost (dev_appserver), but earlier you write as if you had actually uploaded the images to the cloud and mention a very different URL based on some `appstore.com` (?).  dev_appserver only simulates the blobstore, on the local disk (at a path you may set by passing flags `--blobstore_path` when you run `dev_appserver.py`).  I wonder whether you observe the problem locally, or on appspot.com, or confusing the two?

Comment: the problem is on both server, locally and GAE environment. I have figure out the issue little more its not with blob store its with response.write. I my code response.write is not working. I am wondering why this is happening. I think "self.send_blob" is also using response.write internally. I am still finding the solution.

Comment: No, see http://googleappengine.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/python/google/appengine/ext/webapp/blobstore_handlers.py for the source of method `send_blob`: it works on `self.response.headers` only, and does a `self.response.clear()` which likely explains why it looks as if your `response.write` "is not working".  Please edit your Q to show the headers you're getting (e.g with a `curl --dump-header somefile` to your URL, then copy and paste `somefile` as a code block in your question).

Comment: Thank you guys for your help.
Actually I was looking in wrong direction. In application following code was written:
application = core.WSGIApplication()
instead of:
application = webapp2.WSGIApplication()